# Problem with autocompletion of imports in typescript with custom paths

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, server, fastify

I want to create a folder called libs/shared/src, where there is shared stuff between projects, with the client, and the server.

actually I created that folder and inside it is the libs/shared/src/index.ts with this content:

```js
export interface IAppConfig {
  apiEndpoint: string;
  production: boolean;
  environment: string;
}
```

This is how the folders in my project look like:
[image]

create a tsconfig.base.json to share between projects with the following content:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "$libs/*": [
        "libs/shared/src/*"
      ],
      "$libs/": [
        "libs/shared/src/"
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

this is my server/tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
}
```

I tried to make something like this:
server/src/index.ts:

```
const config: IAppConfig = {
  apiEndpoint: 'http://localhost:3000',
  production: false,
  environment: 'development',
};
```

without doing the import, so that the autocomplete helps me, but it does not do it, I do Ctrl + Space for in the data type, so that it generates the import and it does not do it.
[image]

when I do the manual import it works with
`import { IAppConfig } from '$libs/';`
but when I remove the import and do ctrl + space VSCode does not do the autocomplete so that it imports

Comment: what's the point of your `"$libs/": [` ?

Comment: it's hard to see the directory structure from your screenshot. please use something like the `tree` command instead- anything that's text instead of an image and easier to read.

Comment: Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't